# Objects are Losing/Changing shape when used with Ar.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, ar.js

I am just starting with Ar.js. I have a problem where the objects appearing on screen have lost their shapes a bit. First I have this simple A-Frame example which shows a sphere which is perfectly round:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"> </a-sphere>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I use this following code of Ar.js, the same sphere looks like a oval now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://inspiredlabs.github.io/ar.js/markerless.html" />
    <!-- location based aframe v0.9.2 -->
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script><!-- debug -->
    <script>
    const log = console.log;
    window.onload = () => {
      let scene = document.querySelector('a-scene'); /* Apply to whole scene */

      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          let gps = document.createAttribute('gps-entity-place'),
            arjs = document.createAttribute('arjs'),
            
          arjs.value = 'sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth: 640; sourceHeight: 480; trackingMethod: best; debugUIEnabled: false;';
          gps.value = `latitude: ${position.coords.latitude}; longitude: ${position.coords.longitude}`;
          log(gps.value);

          scene.setAttributeNode(gps); /* Apply to whole scene */
          scene.setAttributeNode(arjs);

        });
      }

    };



  </script>
</head>
<a-scene device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: true" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
    <a-entity id="wrapper" position="0 -4 -5 " look-at="[camera]">

        <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>

    </a-entity><!-- /wrapper -->    

    <a-camera camera="fov: 60;" gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having trouble figuring it out. Can anyone help me out here please?

Answer (score 1):

Your sphere is perfectly fine. Shapes get distorted when they're close to the screen edges due to the perspective of the camera but that's absolutely normal. If you retry your first example, get further from the sphere and move it somewhere in a corner you'll see the same distortion you see in the second example. It will seem more natural with a background sky cause the whole view will get distorted in the corners. Nothing to worry about anyway!

Comment: thank you for the quick reply first. Got your point and kind of tested it too by taking the first sphere to the corner. But say, I had to show the second sphere as perfectly round as the first one, what should be the ideal position of camera. I mean what code in the second example above made the sphere go in corner exactly. Please excuse the naiveness of this followup question as I am only starting with A-frame.

Comment: The only way to make it perfect is to have it exactly facing the camera, which is not trivial, but you can do it. In your example, what made it drift away is your wrapper positioned at "0 -4 -5". Your sphere is a child of the wrapper so its position is relative to the wrapper's position.

Comment: I removed the wrapper completely and but still the shape is like a oval. Plus when I change the size of the browser window (minimized a little) then I can see the it perfectly round.

Comment: It may have to do with your camera fov. The default is 80, why did you use 60 instead? https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/camera.html

Comment: I used an old example on stackoverflow as a starting point.But somehow missed this point. But still this seems to have no effect on the shape of the sphere, it is still a bit like oval. plus the changing of screen size is still making it perfectly round. Somehow the size of the  screen on which it is being rendered is affecting the shape of the sphere. but don't know why.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're looking for, sorry... If you want a perfect circle, work in 2 dimensions. You'll always have a perspective effect in 3 dimensions, there's nothing bad about it. Try to play with different parameters to place your element to your liking but it won't appear perfectly round 100% of the time, any camera movement will create perspective, that's the whole purpose of 3D environments.

Comment: I was looking for an example to show what I was looking for. Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9u81_vytOI in this video pause it at 3:04 and the ball and the other turtle object both do not look squashed like the sphere in my case.